# generic container in c# problem of modifying container elements outside the container

Tags: c#, generics, scope, containers

i have a problem in c# programming and need help,
 when i create a generic container in c# and modify one of its element outside the list it's modified too,while i want to keep the elements of the list as it was

i have searched for containers scope or referencing but i've found nothing
btw i faced this problem many times before and i solved with copy constructor as following

```
List<Object> list=new List<Object>();
list.Add(new Object(object) );
```

but in this case my solution has no effect

```
 List<List<Object>> allObjects = new List<List<Object>>(1000);
 List<Object> object = new List<Object>();

 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
            object = new List<Object>();
            //some code here that fill  object list
            allObjects.Add(object);

 }//after filling all the 1000 elements in allObjects list,all the elements of the   //list are 1000 elements with the same value of the last object has been inserted
```

my wrong solution that has no effet on the problem

```
 List<List<Object>> allObjects = new List<List<Object>>(1000);
 List<Object> object = new List<Object>();

 for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
 {
            object = new List<Object>();
            //some code here that fill object list
            allObjects.Add(new List<Object>(object));

 }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to copy a list of objects without retaining the original object references so you may edit the second list (and its objects) without affecting the first?

Comment: i thought that creating a new list of of objects with new is enough are there any other ways to release previously added object list reference ,, thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to do. The code *looks* like you're creating a list of empty lists. I'm guessing this isn't what you want.

Comment: i am creating a list of lists lets name the inner list list1 and the bigger one (list of lists ) list2,,in a loop am trying to fill list1 with some data and at the end of 1 loop i insert list1 in list2...my problem is although i create every start of the loop new empty list1, list2 elements is affected by changing the elements of list1,,and at the end of 1000 loops i got list2 with 1000 elements of 1000 same list1 (the last one added)...hope i've explained it well

Answer (score 1):

Objects in C# are reference types. When you create a new object, .net goes and allocates memory for that object on the heap, the variable itself is essentially a pointer to that object.

A list, "generic container", keeps a list of references to objects, not the objects themselves. When you get an object from the list, ie: var x = list[10], you're really just getting a reference to the same object the list is referencing. By modifying the object, the change will also be reflected in the object contained in the list.

To "modify the object outside the list", and not have that change represented on the object inside the list you'll have to make a copy of that object; there are a handful of ways to do this, depending on what your object really is.

For sake of this example, if you choose to use a struct type instead of the base 'object', you'd experience the behaviour you're looking for. A struct in c# is not a reference type.

Hopefully I haven't confused you more?

After reading your comment, try something like this.

```
List<object> list2 = new List<object>();
for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
   List<object>list1 = new List<object>();
   for(int j = 0; j< 1000; j++)
   {
      list1.Add( "something" + j);
   }
   list2.Add(list1);
}
```

The above will create a list containing 1000, 1000-length lists.

Comment: thankss aloooot for ur help,,but in your code it's supposed to insert a list of objects in another list of objects(that accepts type objects only)!!

Answer (score 0):

The following:

```
object = new List<Object>();
allObjects.Add(object);
```

is equivalent to:

```
allObjects.Add(new List<Object>());
```

which is also equivalent to:

```
object = new List<Object>();
allObjects.Add(new List<Object>(object));
```

In the last case, you're creating an empty list, and then you create another empty list which you fill with the first list.

**Edit**: I'd like to add to what Jon said by leaving this link here: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html

This should help you understand the differences between value and reference types, as I think that's where you're confused.

Comment: thaaanksss 4 ur help ,,i'll check the link

Answer (score 0):

In your comment you say:

```
//after filling all the 1000 elements in allObjects list,all the elements of the
//list are 1000 elements with the same value of the last object has been inserted
```

but if you try something simple like:

```
List<List<int>> allObjects = new List<List<int>>(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var obj = new List<int>();
    obj.Add(i);
    allObjects.Add(obj);
}
```

And inspect the values of the lists in the debugger you'll see that each sub list has one element with the value of i (from 0 to 9).
So, it looks to me like your code is doing the right thing.

Maybe the problem comes after this code when you try to access those elements in the list and you only really access the last element.

Or maybe your Object class is a singleton type class that can only have one instance (probably not just something that comes to mind without knowing any info about Object).

Comment: thaaanks 4 proving and inspiring me :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is inside "*some code here that fill object list*". The objects you put into the inner `List` (that you somewhat confusingly call "`object`") is of reference type, and you probably put references to the same objects into each of the inner Lists. So even thought the inner `List`s themselves are unique instances, the objects inside of them are not.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your inspiring answers & sorry 4 disturbance
actually i've found that the problem is in the part of filling the inner list itself with repeated data (was using a random numbers generator and it was repeating the data )
so it is not a referencing problem as i thought

Comment: Yep, make sure you always seed your random number generator.  I have been a victim of that before. :)